# null context for spring security after successful authentication

Tags: spring, security

I am facing an interesting problem. Implemented custom provider by implementing the `AuthenticationProvider`.

Look at my private method to get security context.  when I used `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()`, I am getting empty context object without authentication but when I read it from session it seems working fine (session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT"))

```
  private SecurityContext getSecurityContext() throws ServiceException {
HttpServletRequest request =
    ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

if (context == null || context.getAuthentication() == null) {
  if (session == null) {
    throw new ServiceException(ErrorCode.INVALID_REQUEST, "User has not logged in");
  }
  context = (SecurityContext) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
}
return context;// SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
```

and when I debug the code the finally block in  **SecurityContextPersistenceFilter**  is getting called emptying the SecurityContextHolder. This is causing empty context object to be created and returned (and so the authentication token is null on subsequent calls).

```
finally {
        SecurityContext contextAfterChainExecution = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        // Crucial removal of SecurityContextHolder contents - do this before anything else.
        **SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();**
        repo.saveContext(contextAfterChainExecution, holder.getRequest(), holder.getResponse());
        request.removeAttribute(FILTER_APPLIED);

        if (debug) {
            logger.debug("SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed");
        }
```

Looks like the `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` filter which is supposed to be executed before actual authentication is getting executed post authentication causing this error behavior.

can you please suggest what could be wrong? Let me investigate more on this.

Also here is my configuration

```
http
    .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(getAccessDeniedHandler()).and()
    .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
    .formLogin()
        .failureUrl("/accessdenied").loginPage("/accessdenied").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler).failureHandler(loginFailedHandler)
        .usernameParameter("j_username").passwordParameter("j_password").and()
    .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll().and()
    .antMatcher("/login")
        .addFilterBefore(captchaFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .csrf().disable()
    .headers().frameOptions().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/accessdenied").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/master/countries").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/master/languages").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/captcha**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/page").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/common/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/member/registration").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/ewallet**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/transfer**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/sales**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/products**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/events").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/archives").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/announcements").authenticated();
```

is this correct? or any changes needed here. I think I am badly missing something here. I want to have a captcha filter enabeld before login filter works.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? If this is executing inside/after the Spring Security filters you are fine. If it is executed before (or outside) the filter chain it will not work. The context will get cleared as soon as the request has finished handling.

Comment: I am calling this method from Spring MVC controller (wrote an abstract controller).

Comment: Remove all the `/xxxx` `permitAll()` and end with a `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`. If the requests don't match they don't pass through the filters. Also make sure that your `springSecurityFilterChain` defined filter matches a url that is handled by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: Ok, I  found the solution. I removed the captcha validation filter and pushed the logic to my custom authentication provider and the problem is solved.

Comment: couldnt post the detailed answer as this site is not allowing me post the same.